# Virtual host with .com not working for xampp

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have added below two settings in httpd-vhosts.conf file. But only first one is working and the second one is not working. Please help.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www_d7test3_com"
ServerName www_d7test3_com
ErrorLog "logs/www_d7test3_com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/www_d7test3_com-access.log" common
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www_d7test3_com"
    ServerName www.d7test3.com
    ErrorLog "logs/www_d7test3_com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/www_d7test3_com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Host File:

```
127.0.0.1          www_d7test3_com
127.0.0.1          www.d7test3.com
```

Comment: They both point to the same DocumentRoot so hard to tell which one works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Either your virtual servers need to point to different directories, log files, etc, or you should use an alias instead of a 2nd vhost entry: [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias)